# Android Adding a polyline to map error

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

My application retrieve a `JSON` from URL and parse the directions from the user's location to the selected marker's location.
The debug shows me that the destination and the source are correct, by the way the app gets stuck when I add the polyline in the map. Here is the code:

```
for(int z = 0; z<list.size()-1;z++){
    LatLng src= list.get(z);
    LatLng dest= list.get(z+1);

    PolylineOptions line=  new PolylineOptions()
        .add(src, dest)
        .width(2)
        .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
        mMap.addPolyline(line);
}
```

And here is the edited logcat:

```
05-20 11:44:04.698 26190-27044/com.example.marco.progettoquinta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
  Process: com.example.marco.progettoquinta, PID: 26190
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
      at maps.f.g.b(Unknown Source)
      at maps.z.D.a(Unknown Source)
      at maps.ag.t.a(Unknown Source)
      at uz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:137)
      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
      at com.example.marco.progettoquinta.MapsActivity.drawPath(MapsActivity.java:210)
      at com.example.marco.progettoquinta.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:80)
      at com.example.marco.progettoquinta.JSONParser.doInBackground(JSONParser.java:35)
      at com.example.marco.progettoquinta.JSONParser.doInBackground(JSONParser.java:18)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It says that the source is unknown but it's actually correct.
Of course this method is implemented in a `AsyncTask.`
Where is the error?

Comment: I tried out your code for adding the `PolylineOptions` into the your `mMap`, I just changed the `src` and `dest` to hardcoded `LatLng`s and it works fine. There might be something else that's causing this error. Have you tried adding logs for the value you get for `src` and `dest`? Would help if you can post further snippets and the full logs.

Comment: I try to force 2 LatLong but doesn't work . How did you make it work ? What do you mean with hardcoded? By the way i retrieve the Json from an Asynch Task and then i pass values to the Main Activity where the method i posted in employed. I believe  it's a problem with threads but i dont know what to do

Comment: I just tried modifying your `.add()` to `.add(new LatLng(-34, 151), new LatLng(-34, 151.1))` then ran the code. When I checked the map (the coordinates are near Sydney, Au), and I see the line. Have you tried putting in Logs where you get the `src` and `dest`? See if your retrieving the correct values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception occurs because you're trying to modify the UI not from the main thread but from the doInBackground of your asynctask (which is required for your request).
Try encapsulating your code into something like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      //do your loop adding polyline
   }
});
```

or get your data returned from your doInBackground and process it to add the polylines in the OnPostExecute.

Comment: Thanks man ,I owe you a coffe. Now it works with no problems.